# Checking an array for palindromes

Tags: javascript, arrays, palindrome

Instead of individually passing through the argument how can I loop through an array and check to see if each word is a palindrome? If it is I want to return the word if not i want to return a 0.

```
var myArray = ['viicc', 'cecarar', 'honda'];    

function palindromize(words) {
    var p = words.split("").reverse().join("");

    if(p === words){
        return(words);
    } else {
        return("0");
    }
}
palindromize("viicc");
palindromize("cecarar");
palindromize("honda");
```

Comment: Look at a for-loop http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp.

Comment: Not trying to answer your question, but just a side-note. Your function does not try to make a given word a palindrome, so maybe calling it `isPalindrome` is better than `palindromize` even if you don't return a boolean value.

Comment: MDN just put up a pretty good JS tutorial; I suggest you run through it to get an idea about JS basics like loops. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    palindromize(myArray[i]);
}
```

I'd suggest you become intimately familiar with them as they are (arguably) the most common type of looping construct.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```
myArray.map(palindromize)
```

```js
var myArray = ['viicc', 'cecarar', 'honda', 'ada'];

function palindromize(word) {
    var p = word.split("").reverse().join("");
    return p === word ? word : 0;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(myArray.map(palindromize), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = ['viicc', 'cecarar', 'honda', 'malayalam' ];   
var b = myArray.filter(function(c,d,f){
var Cur = c.split('').reverse().join('');
if(c == Cur){
console.log( myArray[d] +" " + " is Palindrome" );
}
});
```